# PHP cookie special chars

Tags: php

I'm storing multiple information in cookies in javascript. The information pieces are separated by a "+" sign, like `document.cookie ='cookie1'+'='+inf1+'+'+inf2`.

But when I'm echoing out these cookies from PHP, the separating "+" sign is replaced with a space.

I've tried to echo with addslashes, didn't work. When I'm alerting the the cookie from JS it's alright, it shows the separating "+" sign.

Anyone out there knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

That’s weird — there is no specification that states a cookie should be treated as [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

- [Netscape’s original draft](http://web.archive.org/web/20020803110822/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html) stated:

  > ```
  > NAME=VALUE
  > ```
  >
  > This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space. If there is a need to place such data in the name or value, some encoding method such as URL style `%XX` encoding is recommended, though no encoding is defined or required.

  So this is the plain [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).
- [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) states:

  > ```
  > cookie          =       NAME "=" VALUE *(";" cookie-av)
  > NAME            =       attr
  > VALUE           =       value
  > ```

  Where *attr* and *value* are specified as:

  > ```
  > attr            =       token
  > value           =       word
  > word            =       token | quoted-string
  > ```

  And *token* and *quoted-string* are specified in [HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) and can be represented by these regular expressions respectively:

  ```
    [!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Za-z^_`|~]+
    "([ \x21\x23-\x7E\x80-\xFF]|(\r\n)?[ \t]+|\\[\x00-\x7F])*"
  ```

  So this isn’t *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* either but a different format preferred by HTTP-based extensions.
- [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) doesn’t specify anything different than RFC 2109 regarding the *cookie* syntax:

  > ```
  > cookie          =       NAME "=" VALUE *(";" set-cookie-av)
  > NAME            =       attr
  > VALUE           =       value
  > ```

Thus the `+`, that is only is replaced in *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, should not be replaced by a space in cookies. So this is a wrong behavior by PHP.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to repair this bad behavior?

Comment: @Oblivion: Either use a different separator or encode the value properly by using the JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent`: `document.cookie = 'cookie1='+encodeURIComponent(inf1+'+'+inf2)`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not new issue, but for those, who also runs to this problem, here's my solution:

To solve this error **use escaped characters instead**!

At http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp 
it says:

> This function encodes special characters, with the exception of: * @ -
>   _ + . /

So it means you can insert these characters to the cookie, but won't be able to retrieve through PHP. PHP just and only accepts escaped ASCII chars like '%2B' for '+' '%2A' for '*' etc. Check the Hx column here: http://www.asciitable.com/

So how i solved it (quick and dirty) is that i tried to insert escaped data to the cookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
      var exdate=new Date();
      var n_value = escape(value).replace(/[+]/g,"%2B").replace(/[*]/g,"%2A").replace(/[@]/g,"%40").replace(/[-]/g,"%2D").replace(/[_]/g,"%5F").replace(/[.]/g,"%2E").replace(/[/]/g,"%2F");
      exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
      var c_value = n_value + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
      document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
```

this escapes the rest of the characters, then replace the exceptions ( +-_@*./ ). It's dirty and I'm pretty sure it can be done someway else, like regexp...etc, but it works for now.

Try it, you'll be satisfied with it!

Comment: FYI, w3schools.com is generally considered to be a sub-par resource for programming information - it's a good idea to verify with another source.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `+` with it's url code `%2B`.

```
document.cookie = 'cookie1' + '=' + inf1 + '%2B' + inf2;
```

You should also encode `inf1` and `inf2` if they might contain unencoded strings (if they're numbers, it's fine). Just search google for ["JavaScript urlencode"](http://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScript+urlencode)